# InAppPurchase delegate method calling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have implemented StoreKit delegate methods in AppDelegate.h

My problem is delegate methods are calling perfectly until June-12. I have checked by changing dates of my MAC device. If I change dates as May-15 or Fab-11 or any other before June-12 then below method called and I received response well which is exactly what I want,

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response;
```

but after June 12 Below method is getting called,

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

And got error message as below,

```
Product request failed with error: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

Can anyone help me out here? Why this error is occurring after June 12.

Comment: I'd check in iTunesConnect if anything ran out in time?

Comment: Just checked in this demo, https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit
Same issue is occurring in this also.

Comment: because you are testing on simulator... right?

Comment: @FahimParkar I have tested in simulator as well as in device also.